# Migrating to NavigationStack with .toolbar

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

Currently, I have a settings button inside the toolbar that when I tap on it it will open the `SettingsView()`. Here's my implementation below.

```
@State private var goToSettings = false

NavigationView {
   ZStack {
      NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView(), isActive: $goToSettings) {
      }
   }
   .toolbar {
      Button(role: .destructive, action: {
         goToSettings = true
      }) {
         Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape.fill").foregroundColor(colorForeground)
      }
   }
}
```

Now what confuses me right now is how to implementation this with `NavigationStack`? Where should I put `NavigationLink` because it seems to not work inside the `.toolbar`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was a little straightforward I found out.

Instead of `NavigationView`, you use the new and shiny `NavigationStack`. And use `.navigationDestination()` instead of `NavigationLink`.

```
@State private var goToSettings = false

NavigationStack {
   ZStack {
      // Some more codes
   }
   .toolbar {
      Button(role: .destructive, action: {
         goToSettings = true
      }) {
         Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape.fill").foregroundColor(colorForeground)
      }
   }
   .navigationDestination(isPresented: $goToSettings, destination: {
       SettingsView()
    })
}
```

Comment: did you find this great solution by looking at this info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine no I did not, I had to figure out on my own